# How to ask for referent of pronoun who is the subject in a noun clause

Tags: grammar, clauses

Person 1:

> "I don't understand what it is about."

Person 2 wants to know what 'it' refers to. She could say

> "You don't understand what what is about?" **or else** "What is it that
>   you don't understand what it is about?"

The first is natural but feels colloquial and only really functions in a conversational context. The second is awkward and I'm not sure if it's even grammatical.
Is there another way of constructing this question?

Comment: I'd say, '*What is the thing you don't understand?*'

Answer (score 1):

Between the two sentences provided, the first seems fine and the second is ungrammatical.

There are many different ways to phrase the question in order to determine what *it* is.

I think the most natural question of all is to not refer to *it* in the first place, and just simply ask:

> Person 2: "What do you mean?"

That will let Person 1 clarify.

---

But if I were to question *it* specifically, I would do it a bit differently:

> Person 2: "What do you mean by . . . *it*?"

In live conversation, *it* would be emphasized with a pause and intonation. (My use of ellipses here is only meant exaggerate that.)